# Google Maps Find Nearest Utilities

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

How can I find the nearest hospital/fire department or anything like that around a specific city/area?

If you go to maps.google.com, then you type "San Francisco", then type "hospital", you will see all the hospitals around San Francisco.

Can the same thing be applied using geocoder?

Thanks a bunch!

**Additional Note**:
I'm trying to use the geocoder manually, instead of using the search bar. That way I can control the outcome of the search-results.

Comment: Ideally, if you found an answer helpful you should upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use HTTP Geocoder with Viewport Biasing (see: [ReverseGeocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#ReverseGeocoding) and [Viewport Biasing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#Viewports)) and filter the JSON result.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.

It is explained here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#LocalSearch

See an example here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/control-googlebar.html

Comment: Thanks. But the problem with the search-bar, is that I can't control the results. I would expect to use something similar to GClientDecoder so that I can manipulate the result before being shown to the map.