# How to retrieve locations of theaters through google

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, maps, location

I am not sure if this is even possible, or if I am just in need of a database or something. However, I am wondering if there is any way in an android app to get a list of the lat and long of specific buildings near the user's location. Basically what I want is for my app to have a set of known theaters for example, and when the user is within a certain radius of these locations then an action will occur. I know how to do the second part using the location manager and firing an intent when the user is within the specified radius, see [the google developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html). However, I do not know how to get the location of the theaters in the city or area that the user resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/688236/804503):

> Use HTTP Geocoder with Viewport Biasing (see: [ReverseGeocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding) and
>   [Viewport](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#Viewports) Biasing) and filter the JSON result.